# Should I import 'fs' or 'node:fs' in Bun?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs, bun

I am trying to migrating my Node.js project to Bun. My project uses the 'fs' package in many places. I found many Bun migration examples where they import the 'fs' package as 'node:fs'. But importing as 'fs' works fine without any errors and performance issues.

Should I leave my imports as 'fs' or change to 'node:fs' (and other packages that can be imported as 'node:...')? Are there performance differences?

Comment: No difference. Always prefer the use of `node:` prefix for core modules that are shipped as part of Node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't imagine there are differences. (Try importing both and see if they're the same object with `===`?)

You can also import `fs` in Node as `node:fs` (so as to make it clear it's an internal module), so both are compatible both ways.

Comment: I imported them as fs and node_fs. `console.log(fs === node_fs)` prints `true`

Comment: There you go then, they're the same.